# Azure web app not encoding %2F as forward slash in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure

My Azure Web Service app is not encoding %2F as a forward slash in url. For example:

`www.website.com/random%2Ftest` should encode as `www.website.com/random/test`

After some extensive googling I discovered it could be fixed using the web.config file. My app was missing the web.config file in `wwwroot` so I added the following and restarted the service:

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But still no luck.

Comment: is this asp.net app?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Would be handy to see how you encode the forward slash and then how you tried to decode it. Where does the string come from? Your own coding or is it sent from somewhere? BTW you state you want to encode %2F, but what you mean is you want to decode it. %2F is the encoded version, the slash the decode version...

Comment: Does the `web.config`‘s `webServer` element even get utilized for Ruby on Rails apps? I wouldn’t expect it to, but I’m not used to running Ruby on Rails on top of IIS, so might be missing some interoperability point.

Comment: Where are you seeing this getting encoded?